# Font Awesome Icons missing

Tags: font-awesome

I have tried several different ways of adding font awesome icons by using , , etc. I have tried many of the solutions suggested here, however I am unable to get any of it to produce icons.

Thank you for your guidance.

https://codepen.io/rquery/pen/ebPwPy?editors=1100

## HOBBIES

```
  <span class="fa fa-camera"><style="font-size:36px;"></span>

  <span class="fa fa-paint-brush"><style="font-size:36px;">   </span>

  <span class="fa fa-plane" style="font-size:36px;"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: You just had a typo on your css link...it's fixed here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJmBqo?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

"cdnjs.cloudflare.c  om"

there is space in the above link in given example, correct the cdn url.

Comment: Yay!  Thank you very much!